# Changing the onclick of every <li> element in a <ol>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, onclick

I have a jQueryUI sortable list of li-Buttons with following markup:

```
<ol id="tracks" class="ui-sortable">
<li class="pl_clipEntry ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
    <span class="pl_slot_1_clipNumber_6">6. </span>
    <span class="pl_clipName">
        <button class="pl_entry" onclick="emitCommand('goto: clip id: 6')">Clip Copy 3.mov</button>
    </span>
    <span class="pl_clipLength">(00min17sec)</span>
</li>
</ol>
```

These Items are dragged from another list, where their onclick has its good use
Now everytime the list is sorted (or a new item is inserted), i want to overwrite the onclick, so that the items in THIS list have a different function (in fact, it's going to be a playlist, that's why the onclick-command can't be the same as in the file-list)

i can't figure out how exactly to do this.

This is called on every list-update:

```
function updatePlaylist () {
    var list = $("#tracks");
    list.children(':not(.placeholder)').each(function(index) {
        console.log($(this).childNodes[1].text());  // to check if it works
        //$(this).children[1].attr("onclick","play_clip:" + index);
    });
};
```

so, in plain: i want to set the onclick of each li > span > button to "play_clip6" etc.

i've tried it with children[1] and childnodes[1], but they all print undefined.

i suppose it's something about the scope of "this", or some other thing i've overlooked.. but shouldn't this work? i'm stuck :(
thanks

Comment: It's clear, but need to know how is binded the onclick on the original list, from the elements that was dragged. It's by a function `jQuery`/`javascript` or directly inline with `onclick` event?

Comment: the items are copied 1:1 from the original list. so they are inline "onclick='emitCommand("play clip 6")' (created on receiving the file list like (clip_number) + (clip_name) + (playtime), onclick="goto: clip" + (clip_number). each in a span. like in the example above.
i need to FIND those exact items (the BUTTON that has the onclick) and CHANGE their onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are missing is the parameter for the referenced element in the each function.

HTML

```
<ol id="tracks">
    <li>Track 1 <span style="color:red;">sp1</span>  <span style="color:blue;">Play 1</span>

    </li>
    <li>Track 2 <span style="color:red;">sp1</span>  <span style="color:blue;">Play 2</span>

    </li>
    <li>Track 3 <span style="color:red;">sp1</span>  <span style="color:blue;">Play 3</span>

    </li>
    <li>Track 4 <span style="color:red;">sp1</span>  <span style="color:blue;">Play 4</span>

    </li>
    <li class="placeholder">Move Track Here</li>
</ol>
<button id="changeIt">Change The Click Event</button>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $("#tracks").children(":not(.placeholder)").each(function (index, elem) {
        var cElem = $(elem).children().eq(1);
        $(cElem).click(function () {
            alert("before: " + $(cElem).text());
        });
    });
});
$("#changeIt").click(function () {
    $("#tracks").children(":not(.placeholder)").each(function (index, elem) {
        var cElem = $(elem).children().eq(1);
        $(cElem).attr('onclick', '').unbind('click');
        $(cElem).click(function () {
            alert("after: " + $(cElem).text());
        });
    });
});
```

**Edit for selecting button inside**

HTML

```
<ol id="tracks">
    <li>Track 1 <span style="color:red;">sp1</span>  <span style="color:blue;"><button>Play 1</button></span>

    </li>
    <li>Track 2 <span style="color:red;">sp1</span>  <span style="color:blue;"><button>Play 2</button></span>

    </li>
    <li>Track 3 <span style="color:red;">sp1</span>  <span style="color:blue;"><button>Play 3</button></span>

    </li>
    <li>Track 4 <span style="color:red;">sp1</span>  <span style="color:blue;"><button>Play 4</button></span>

    </li>
    <li class="placeholder">Move Track Here</li>
</ol>
<button id="changeIt">Change The Click Event</button>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $("#tracks").children(":not(.placeholder)").each(function (index, elem) {
        var cElem = $(elem).children().eq(1).children().eq(0);
        $(cElem).click(function () {
            alert("before: " + $(cElem).text());
        });
    });
});
$("#changeIt").click(function () {
    $("#tracks").children(":not(.placeholder)").each(function (index, elem) {
        var cElem = $(elem).children().eq(1).children().eq(0);
        $(cElem).attr('onclick', '').unbind('click');
        $(cElem).click(function () {
            alert("after: " + $(cElem).text());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: but i want to target the second child of each li... not the li itself (the BUTTON inside it, to be exact)

Comment: Updated with the code for selecting the second child.

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle for the code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JonTurlington/yLuaz4mf/4/)

Comment: This code is updated to select the button inside the second span.

Comment: you, sir, are my hero for today :) this seems to be the right track <3
but another problem came up: it doesn't change the onclick, but instead fires the event (with the correct function call) everytime the list is updated (around 1000 times a second when i drag an item inside :D ). but i hope i'll be able to fix this tomorrow.

is there something wrong with the way i wrote it? i just took $(button).click(emitCommand('test'));
is this correct? like i said, it does call the function, but not when i want it to.

Comment: Yes, when you don't provide a function() parameter it will fire immediately,
**$(button).click(function(){emitCommand('test');});** will resolve

Comment: NICE! that did it. thank you very much! a thousand kisses :-*

Comment: oh one last thing.... how do i get the index of the li? i just put $(button).click(function(){emitCommand(index);}); for testing, but it resolves to undefined, even though it's list.children(':not(.placeholder)').each(function(index,elem) {

Comment: Actually you are probably losing _scope_.  if you assign to **currentIndex = index** (don't include var so that the variable becomes global by default, and use currentIndex inside the **function()** area). Do it just before you call the $(button).click(function()......

[Check out the updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JonTurlington/yLuaz4mf/7/)

Comment: update: it works now, if i don't pass index alone ('test' + index). as that is what i needed, i will be satisfied with this. thanks :)